# How can I manipulate params inserted into and Edit form?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an object with a Time attribute. When the attribute is inserted into my Edit form it appears like:

```
2018-06-06 12:00:00 -0400
```

Is it possible to instead have the form show:

```
12:00 PM
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Take a look at [`Time#strftime`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use strftime as following

```
 created_at = Time.now
 created_at.strftime("%I:%M %p")
```

which will produce out put like below based on your time

```
 "03:23 PM"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use strftime: [strftime doc](https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime)

`datetime_var.strftime("%I:%M %p")`